# Mongodb to Kafka Connector

Tags: mongodb

Can you help how to configure the connect-mongo-source.properties?

below are the **connect-mongo-source.properties**

```
    name=mongodb-source-connector
    connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
    mongodb.hosts=mongodb://admin:password@ipaddress:27017/test
    mongodb.name=mongo_conn
    initial.sync.max.threads=1
    tasks.max=1
```

I am getting this error

```
 [2020-04-22 16:26:58,723] ERROR Error while reading the 'shards' collection in the 'config' database: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, 
servers=

[{address=test?authsource=admin&replicaset=quickfoodcluster-shard-0&readpreference=primary&appname=mongodb%20compass%20community&ssl=true:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, 
exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: test?authsource=admin&replicaset=quickfoodcluster-shard-0&readpreference=primary&appname=mongodb%20compass%20community&ssl=true}, 
caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: test?authsource=admin&replicaset=quickfoodcluster-shard-0&readpreference=primary&appname=mongodb%20compass%20community&ssl=true}}, 

{address=quickfoodcluster-shard-00-01-zxbxk.azure.mongodb.net:27017, 
type=UNKNOWN, 
state=CONNECTING, 
exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: quickfoodcluster-shard-00-01-zxbxk.azure.mongodb.net}, 
caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: quickfoodcluster-shard-00-01-zxbxk.azure.mongodb.net}}] (io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ReplicaSetDiscovery)
    com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, 
servers=[{address=test?authsource=admin&replicaset=quickfoodcluster-shard-0&readpreference=primary&appname=mongodb%20compass%20community&ssl=true:27017, 
type=UNKNOWN, 
state=CONNECTING, 
exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: test?authsource=admin&replicaset=quickfoodcluster-shard-0&readpreference=primary&appname=mongodb%20compass%20community&ssl=true}, 
caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: test?authsource=admin&replicaset=quickfoodcluster-shard-0&readpreference=primary&appname=mongodb%20compass%20community&ssl=true}}, 
{address=quickfoodcluster-shard-00-01-zxbxk.azure.mongodb.net:27017, 
type=UNKNOWN, state=CON


NECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: quickfoodcluster-shard-00-01-zxbxk.azure.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: quickfoodcluster-shard-00-01-zxbxk.azure.mongodb.net}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't use DSN string in `mongodb.hosts`, it should be `host:port` and user and password be provided in a separate field as mentioned in document [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/connectors/mongodb.html#mongodb-connector-properties).

```json
name=mongodb-source-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
mongodb.hosts=ipaddress:27017
mongodb.user=admin
mongodb.password=password
mongodb.name=mongo_conn
initial.sync.max.threads=1
tasks.max=1
```

Answer (score -1):

mongodb.hosts needs to be like this, with separate entries for username and password:

> mongodb.hosts=replicasetname/IPADDRESS:PORT
>
> mongodb.user=USERNAME
>
> mongodb.password=PASSWORD

Comment: Can you provide a source? Because I can't see it in the documentation that `mongodb.hosts` needs to be prefixed with the replicasetname.

Comment: @soatz Please have a look at example part https://docs.confluent.io/debezium-connect-mongodb-source/current/mongodb_source_connector_config.html

Comment: That documentation is a bit misleading, since even if `mongodb.members.auto.discover` is set to true, the only way to make it work was with: 
`replicasetname/PRIMARYshard:PORT`
----
The problem arised only when using Mongo on Atlas platform, anyway thanks @ROHIT KHURANA!